# Why does profiler in QNX Momentics IDE not show source while debugger does?

Tags: c++, profiling, arm64, qnx, momentics

I have built a C++ application with an gcc 8.3.0 cross-compiler for AArch64 using the compile arguments `-no-pie -g` to enable debugging and profiling (without instrumentation, just with sampling). I have used `-O0` and `-O2`, but the effect described below stays the same.

I have set up a path mapping for the source path lookup in Momentics IDE. When I run the application in the debugger, everything works as expected and I can step through the source code of a file I am interested in.

When I switch the same launch configuration to "Profile", select "Sampling" as profiling method and then run the profiler, I can see in the "Execution Time" view how much time is spent in a method of the respective source file. As soon as I double-click onto that file to see where the time is being spent, I get the error message "Unable to open source file - The profiler was unable to determine the source file this symbol is in. Debug information may be missing or symbol does not belong to analyzed binary."

This error message **must** be wrong, right? If it was true, I could not step through exactly that file in the debugger.

What can be the reason for the error message? I have no function instrumentation or call count instrumentation, but I don't necessarily need it for profiling, correct?